# Need to find out the date from certain period and number of days

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need the result as given by date by user.
Suppose if the user gives the date 2013-01-14 and total days  = 2, i need to filter out

```
2013-01-10
2013-01-11
2013-01-14
2013-01-15
2013-01-16
```

and it should not return the date of 12 and 13. ie 2013-01-13, 2013-01-12

Similarly if the total days = 3 
then

```
    2013-01-09
    2013-01-10
    2013-01-11
    2013-01-14
    2013-01-15
    2013-01-16
    2013-01-17
```

How can i possibly get this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `DateAdd()` function:

```
declare @Number int = 2, @Date Date = '20130114' --yyyymmdd format

select col1, col2
from yourTable
where dateCol >= dateAdd(day, -1*@Number, @Date) and dateCol< @Date
```

**Update:** Your description is not very clear I think what you need is to select records within +/-  range from the given date.

```
select col1, col2
from yourTable
where dateCol >= dateAdd(day, -1*@Number, @Date) and dateCol <= dateAdd(day, @Number, @Date)
```